# Google App Engine Go SDK update problems with template

Tags: google-app-engine, sdk, go

I`ve just updated my GAE Go SDK to the newest release. I ran the gofix
on my code, but there were still some errors. The code used to look:

```
   AnkietaTemp = template.New(nil)
   err := AnkietaTemp.ParseFile("ankieta/ankieta.html")
```

but now passing nil doesn't seem to work, so I replaced it into:

```
   AnkietaTemp = template.New("")
   _, err := AnkietaTemp.ParseFile("ankieta/ankieta.html")
```

Tried running my app, but in HTML source I get:

```
 <td width="400"><img src="images/{.section One}{@}{.end}"
alt="images/{.section One}{@}{.end}" width="100%"/></td>
```

Instead of a neat reference to an image file.

What is the proper way to parse the template files now, after the
update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the new `template` package the template tag syntax changed, as you can see in the [documentation](http://golang.org/pkg/template/). E.g. dot (`.`) is used instead of `@` for referencing the "current" item and the template tags are indicated with two curly braces instead of one.

Edit: Oh, and there's no `.section` tag any more. You didn't provide the structure you pass to template's `Execute()` method so I can't provide details on how mitigate that exactly, but I guess you can use `{{with}}` tag like `{{with One}}{.}{{end}}` or maybe `{{.One}}`.

Comment: Found some example that used {{printf "%s" .One |html}} in the html file.